# Android app goes back to previous screen after refreshing recycler view with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a training app. What I'm trying to achieve is to delete and add items to my recyclerview that is pulling data from a Firebase database.
The problem is that after deleting some of the data, the app will just go back to the previous screen and I cannot find any error messages causing it.

Here is my code for the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    courseList = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Course> coursesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    removeCourseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (courseRecyclerAdapter.mCheckStates.size() == 0) {
                Utils.createAlertDialogWithOKButton(AdminManageCoursesActivity.this, "Alert", "Please select an item to remove");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < courseList.size(); i++) {
                    if (courseRecyclerAdapter.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                        coursesToRemove.add(courseList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                //get all the ticked checkboxes
                courseList.removeAll(coursesToRemove);
                //change the values in the DB

                for(Course course: coursesToRemove) {
                    Utils.courseReference.child(course.getCourseName()).removeValue();
                }

                //delete all user progress in db for deleted course
                for(User user : users) {
                    HashMap<String, Progress> removedProgressMap = user.getCourseProgress();
                    for(Course course: coursesToRemove) {
                        removedProgressMap.remove(course.getCourseName());
                    }
                    user.setCourseProgress(removedProgressMap);
                    Utils.userReference.child(Utils.removeSpecialCharactersFromEmail(user.getEmailAddress())).setValue(user);
                }
            }
        }
    });


    //get all the courses from the db
    Utils.courseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            courseList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                courseList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Course.class));
            }
            //set the screen to the current courses initially
            courseRecyclerAdapter = new CourseRecyclerAdapter(courseList, true, null);
            coursesRecyclerView.setAdapter(courseRecyclerAdapter);
            filteredCourseList = courseList;

            //get all the user progresses from the db
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(AdminManageCoursesActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    users = new ArrayList<>();
    Utils.userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                users.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Logcat error:

```
2021-03-09 16:24:46.798 1329-1498/? E/WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{eea87f3 u0 com.example.medicalEquipmentTraining/com.example.medicalEquipmentTraining.AdminManageCoursesActivity EXITING}
android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:575)
    at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:829)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3793)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5433)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

Another one that might be (?) related

```
2021-03-09 17:19:56.989 1329-1368/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{e20d4c9 u0 com.example.medicalEquipmentTraining/com.example.medicalEquipmentTraining.AdminManageCoursesActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1248 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1229 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:1284 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStoppedLocked:2776 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.activityStopped:2512 android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub.onTransact:2280 android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal:1056
```

EDIT:

After further debugging it looks like the problem is caused by this code:

```
for(User user : users) {
                HashMap<String, Progress> removedProgressMap = user.getCourseProgress();
                for(Course course: coursesToRemove) {
                    removedProgressMap.remove(course.getCourseName());
                }
                user.setCourseProgress(removedProgressMap);
                Utils.userReference.child(Utils.removeSpecialCharactersFromEmail(user.getEmailAddress())).setValue(user);
            }
```

I'm still not getting any error messages in logcat related to that and the database interaction is successfully completed. It just goes back to the previous activity... Any idea how to resolve this, I tried to fetch the data together in one query and I tried to set a a CompletionListener when setting the value in Firebase. If I tried it without the second database update, it is working fine.
So I think my issue is with trying to update two separate nodes?

Comment: there must be some error in the screen, please check logcat for that

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Thank you, I added the log for the database error, but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: When I removed the filter from Logcat I found this error among many others... I updated the original  post with that. Do you think this could be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like the whole app restarted because I was updating the current signed in user in the second query. Once I avoid doing that it is working fine.